# Listing function points in a spreadsheet/excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I am working on a Pre-Calculus Polar coordinate graphing project that incorporates some creativity; My current plan has me graphing the Nautilus Shell as my focal point.

However, I have to list points for every 15 degrees or rotation.

(θ+15°k, r), k = 0, 1, 2, . . . 1,152.

How do I list every r value from 0 degrees to 17,280 degrees in a google spreadsheet or excel?

Thank you in advance.

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsmZe.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tFer.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kq2KK.png

Comment: write your formula in one cell, copy/drag it down. write your constant in an adjacent cell, increment it down. done

Comment: @Máté Juhász Yes. Thank you!

Comment: @Máté Juhász Do you mind creating the spreadsheet with the listed polar equation because I'm not all that familiar with the syntax?

Comment: @LandryRatliff that's a different question. Please ask it in a separate post. Also please include your best attempt and explain how that doesn't work. That's the format of question most likely to get quick answer.

Comment: Interesting. Did you manage to do this? Can you tell us the source for your Nautilus shell equation. Some remarks: SQRT(SIN(...)) will give an error since Excel can't handle negative square roots. Is that an error or are you supposed to do complex math? Also note you will have to convert the polar coordinates to X and Y in order for Excel Scatter plot to work.